# From which number did I get this text?

Tags: iphone, contacts, sms, contacts.app

I received a text from a number. My contact list had that number saved as well as 3 other numbers in the same contact card.

How do I get to know which number had sent the text, when it shows only the name?  (the “recent” thing, in Phone app does not seem to work.)

I worked around it by deleting each number from the contact card and seeing how the “sender” changed.

There ought to be an easy way for the same.

Comment: It looks like you have your answer - is there something that’s still needed? if you can edit the question to show how you’re seeing numbers, perhaps we can assist you further

Comment: What I did was a insanely long process. I AM SURE THERE WILL BE AN EASIER ANSWER.

Comment: Kindly refrain from using all CAPS when trying to convey a point; it’s the written equivalent of yelling and considered very bad form.

Comment: If the solution provided in the answers to the question linked on top do not work in your case, please *edit* your question to explain what you have tried where the result was different than expected. Screenshots will help in case your phone doesn't show something you expect to see.

Answer (score 2):

Go to their contact info and there should be a mark next to number which sent the most recent text.